# How to simplify Hasura's tracked relationship query responses?

Tags: graphql, hasura

Curious if I constructed and tracked this m2m relationship correctly. Seems strange that every object in those arrays are named `"user": {...}` or `"pip": {...}`

[image]

Seems like these both should work

[image]

**Update with screenshots:**

Users table relationships:
[image]

Pips table relationships:
[image]

Comment: `users` at root level is an array of `user` object while deeper `users` is a name of relation ... to target types usually by structures named `edges`/`nodes` (relay style cursor/pagination)

Comment: Did you track both relationships?

Comment: Yeah I'm tracking both the relationships.

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the relationship definitions in Hasura for both?

Comment: @AbrahamLabkovsky Hey sorry it took a couple days but I just added the pictures of the relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no automatic way to "hide" the join table from the GraphQL query and response. You need to traverse through the join table to get back the results you want from both directions so you can't avoid it using the default generated API.

It is possible to [extend the GraphQL API using SQL Views](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/schema/views.html#) if you want to try and "flatten" things from the perspective of people consuming this data.

Alternatively, I'd recommend calling the relationship something different to make it obvious that you're navigating through a join table. I'd recommend actually calling the relationship `user_pips` instead of `pips` as it makes it more clear what you're actually retrieving.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, Jesse. Good advice on the `user_pips` naming convention. I originally thought it'd be cool to go `users > pips` but if I can't get rid of the join table you're exactly right.